# Is it reasonable to put a crown on a baby tooth?

Tags: tooth-decay

4 year old has dermatomyositis ( rare , 1 in a million for juvenile males); an immune disorder. He has been getting meds  and can walk again. However a side affect of meds is that he has 8 cavities. The dentist says at least one needs a crown. I expect he will need more before long.

Comment: You'll need to consult another dentist if you want a second opinion. Medical advice is off topic here.

Comment: What medications are being blamed for the cavities?

Comment: I gues I could ask the question with no background, then I don't think it would be advice.

Comment: I got a different spin on the situation;  The meds required hours of IV every week in addition to daily shots ( for a 3 yr old) so inducements and rewards of candy were liberally applied.

Comment: That makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that dentists might want to crown a baby tooth instead of removing it is to prevent crowding of the jaw from premature tooth loss, and to prevent the decay spreading to adjacent teeth.

http://www.aapd.org/events/stainless_steel_crown_indications_and_technique_for_placement/

Comment: Why do you answer questions you know are off topic and the plague of this site?

Comment: @CareyGregory I did not provide specific medical advice.  I just pointed out that pediatric dentists do this procedure.  If you thought the question were off topic I expected it to be down voted.